# Elastic Search using NEST - Results different in debug and browser mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST for ES in .net

This is how im indexing a doc. (Wrote all the elastic client connections in a different class called Settings)

so on a button click

```
client = Settings.connection();
          var res1 = new Class1
            {
                Id = 1,
                Ans = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
            };
    if (client.IndexExists("zzz").Exists == true)
            {
                client.Index(res1);
            }
```

string  ans = getInfo();

process(ans);

```
    public string getInfo(){
        string wordInfoQuery = @"{
                        ""query"": {
                            ""match_phrase"":{
                                ""Answer"":{
                                              ""query"": ""brown dog"",
                                              ""slop"": "3"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }";


              try
                        {

                            if (client != null)
                            {
                                var callResult = client.LowLevel.Search<string>(wordInfoQuery);
                                reply = callResult.Body.ToString();
                                e.Write(callResult.Body);
                            }

                        }
                               return reply;
    }

public void process(string answer)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
            {
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(answer);
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                float score;
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(m))
                {
                    string json1 = r.ReadToEnd();
                    JObject jobj1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
                    JToken agg1 = jobj1.GetValue("hits")["max_score"];
                    if (agg1!=null) //getting an error here most of the times. if the max_score field is null (for eg: instead of brown dog if i send "tax" as a query term)
                    {
                        score = agg1.ToObject<float>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        score = 0;
                    }

                }

            }

        }

class Settings{
public static ElasticClient connection()
        {
            configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"];//stored the url in web.config (http://localhost:9200)

            node = new Uri(configvalue1);
            settings = new ConnectionSettings(node)
                .DefaultIndex("zzz")
                .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Class1), "omg"));
            client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            if (client.IndexExists("zzz").Exists)
            {
                client.DeleteIndex("zzz"); //i want to index only one doc at a time. so deleting and creating everytime i click on the button
                client.CreateIndex("zzz");
            }


            return client;
        }
    }
```

In the above code, when i run the code in debug mode, I'm getting a successful post message with query result(for eg. max_Score = 0.28) where as if i run the code in browser mode, it is still making a call to ES , but the result is empty(max_score =""). I dont know why is this happening. 
someone please help in solving this.

thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "run the code in browser mode"?
run a web debugging proxy like Fiddler and inspect what the request and response looks like for each.

Comment: i meant direct running it by clicking on the run on google chrome button in visual studio

Comment: In order to be able to help, you're going to need to put more detail in your question. If you could put a complete example that replicates the problem, that would be really useful - for example, index creation, documents indexed, plus the search that you have. Basically, the more _relevant_ information that you can provide, the more likely that you're going to get an answer that really helps you.

Comment: Hi Russ.. Edited the questiona and added the data you have asked for. please check it once.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the low level client and doing the json parsing yourself instead of letting NEST take care of it for you?

Comment: i used a low level client as suggested by you on elastic search discussion forum as I'm passing a string query directly.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-pass-raw-query-to-elastic-search-and-handle-the-raw-json-response/46932/5

Comment: I didn't _suggest_ to use raw json strings, you asked _how_ to pass raw json strings :) Unless you have a good reason to do so, I'd use either the fluent API, object initializer syntax, at least until you are more familiar with Elasticsearch. I think it'll make it easier to get more up to speed.

Comment: yeah im sorry.. i asked how to pass raw jsons. And I chose to use raw json as there are some instances where the query is very big and i found it difficult converting it into Lambda query . 


_Just for info:_ And in the current query, the query term and slop may change based on the selection made by the user using the interface(i designed the interface in such way)

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1. You use `"Answer"` as the field name for the `match_phrase` query in your json but NEST by default will camel case all CLR property names when mapping, indexing, searching, etc. This should be `"answer"` or [change the default field name inference on Connection Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/field-inference.html#camel-casing)
2. When there are no results for a `match_phrase` query, `max_score` will be `null` so you will need to handle this case. In your example, a `slop` of 3 produces no hits for the query so `max_score` is `null`. If you change `slop` to 5, you get the document back and a value for `max_score`.
3. I'd recommend using the [Fluent API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/match-phrase-usage.html#_fluent_dsl_example_32) or the [Object Initializer Syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/match-phrase-usage.html#_object_initializer_syntax_example_32) in NEST unless you have good reason not to (and if you do have a reason, we'd love to know!). There are  **[usage examples of all of the Query DSL for NEST 2.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/query-dsl.html)** that should hopefully help :)

An example

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "zzz";

    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
            .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Class1), "omg"))
            .PrettyJson()
            .DisableDirectStreaming()
            .OnRequestCompleted(response =>
                {
                    // log out the request
                    if (response.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            $"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri} \n" +
                            $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri}");
                    }

                    // log out the response
                    if (response.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                                 $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                                 $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                                 $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                    }
                });

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
    {
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);
    }

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.Index(new Class1
    {
        Id = 1,
        Answer = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    }, i => i.Refresh());

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Class1>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .MatchPhrase(mp => mp
                .Field(f => f.Answer)
                .Query("brown dog")
                .Slop(5)
            )
        )
    );

    Console.WriteLine(searchResponse.MaxScore);
}

public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set;}
}
```

Writes out the following to the console

```
HEAD http://localhost:9200/zzz?pretty=true
Status: 200

------------------------------

DELETE http://localhost:9200/zzz?pretty=true
Status: 200
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}

------------------------------

PUT http://localhost:9200/zzz?pretty=true 
{}
Status: 200
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}

------------------------------

PUT http://localhost:9200/zzz/omg/1?pretty=true&refresh=true 
{
  "id": 1,
  "answer": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
}
Status: 201
{
  "_index" : "zzz",
  "_type" : "omg",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "created" : true
}

------------------------------

POST http://localhost:9200/zzz/omg/_search?pretty=true 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "answer": {
        "type": "phrase",
        "query": "brown dog",
        "slop": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
Status: 200
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.07829509,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "zzz",
      "_type" : "omg",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.07829509,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "answer" : "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
      }
    } ]
  }
}

------------------------------

0.07829509
```

Comment: thanks once again.. You saved me this time too.. :) and as recommended i will try to use Fluent or object Initializer syntax. Thanks once again..