# LINQ expressions for Elasticsearch NEST query

Tags: c#, linq, elasticsearch, nest

I setting up an index as below. But now I have a requirement because of which i need to tweak the indexing style. (i have to add analyzer field in the below code).

Reference[My previous question and its answer]: [Elastic Search using NEST - Results different in debug and browser mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732860/elastic-search-using-nest-results-different-in-debug-and-browser-mode?noredirect=1#comment61056583_36732860)

How can I rewrite

```
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
        .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Class1), "omg"))
        .PrettyJson()
        .DisableDirectStreaming());
```

with the mapping settings like below.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "Class1": {
      "properties": {
        "Answer": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my take on answer:

```
 settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
              .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
              .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Class1), "omg"))
              .PrettyJson()
              .DisableDirectStreaming();

            var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(defaultIndex)
                            .Mappings(ms => ms
                            .Map<Class1>(m => m
                            .Properties(ps => ps
                            .String(s=>s
                            .Name(n=>n.Ans)
                            .Analyzer("english")))));
```

I think I'm missing a link somewhere between the index creation and mappings. Though it didnt show an error while coding, the output is not as expected.

TIA

Comment: I just tried it on Sense plugin to check if it is working. Then tried to tweak your code  a little by adding `.MapPropertiesFor<>` after  `.MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Class1), "omg"))`

What i thought was, after defaulting the names to that of class1, then we need to give their properties, so tried for `.MapProperties`

Comment: Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html

Comment: Thanks Russ. Will have a look at it and get back with the answer.

Comment: @RussCam I tried creating an index descriptor for the same but the output is not as expected. Did i miss any link ? Do I have to pass this descriptor to the settings?

Answer (score 1):

A `CreateIndexDecriptor<T>` is a descriptor for creating an index, but you need to pass it to the `IElasticClient.CreateIndex()` method in order to create the index in Elasticsearch.

```
void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, new InMemoryConnection())
             .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
             .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(Class1), "omg"))
             .PrettyJson()
             .DisableDirectStreaming();

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    client.CreateIndex("new-index", c => c
        .Mappings(ms => ms
            .Map<Class1>(m => m
                .Properties(ps => ps
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(n => n.Ans)
                        .Analyzer("english")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
}

public class Class1
{
    public string Ans { get; set;}
}
```

The request to Elasticsearch looks like

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "omg": {
      "properties": {
        "ans": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```